# DD4T - what is the recommended way to configure default controllers and actions?

Tags: dd4t

In earlier versions of the framework, default controllers and actions were configured with

```
<add key="Controller" value="TridionComponent"/>
<add key="Action" value="Component"/>
```

as [blogged by Albert Romkes](https://albertromkes.com/2012/01/20/dd4t-continued-rendering-component-presentations/)

In a [more recent post by Katarina Stojanovski](http://blog.trivident.com/dd4t-page-and-content-viewmodels/) the advice is to use the following:

```
<add key="DD4T.ComponentPresentationController" value="Component" />
<add key="DD4T.ComponentPresentationAction" value="ComponentModel" />
```

I have noticed that in [DD4T.Utils.DD4TConfiguration](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/blob/develop/source/DD4T.Utils/DD4TConfiguration.cs#L85) the properties that expose these settings are marked as obsolete. It's not clear why.

So, on the basis that I'm starting a brand new DD4T application and wish to follow current good practice, how should I proceed?

Comment: Obsolete annotation on ComponentPresentationController and ComponentPresentationAction is wrong. created a ticket for it https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/issues/81

Comment: Thanks @SiawashShibani - that helps. So all I need now is some clarity over the differences between the other settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web.config Configuration should be:

```
<add key="DD4T.ComponentPresentationController" value="Component" />
<add key="DD4T.ComponentPresentationAction" value="ComponentModel" />
```

These values are used as a default for Controller and Action for a components, and could be overwritten by metadata on the Component Template.

For the above configuration the following controller should exist in your app:

```
 public class ComponentController : ModelControllerBase
    {
        public ComponentController(IPageFactory pageFactory, IComponentPresentationFactory componentPresentationFactory, ILogger logger, IDD4TConfiguration dd4tConfiguration, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory) : base(pageFactory, componentPresentationFactory, logger, dd4tConfiguration, viewModelFactory)
        {
        }
        public override ActionResult ComponentModel()
        {
            return base.ComponentModel();
        }
    }
```

The controller above assumes that you're using a strongly typed viewmodels for your application, and your ViewModels are implementing `IRenderableViewModel` interface.

```
    [ContentModel("article", true)]
    public class Article : ViewModelBase, IRenderableViewModel
    {

        [TextField]
        public string Heading { get; set; }

        [RenderData]
        public IRenderData RenderData { get; set; }
    }
```

The logic for `RenderData` can be found [here](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.MVC/blob/develop/source/DD4T.Mvc/ViewModels/Attributes/Attributes.cs).